# HTTP POST-GET application in Java

Tags: java, http, post, get

I want to create a small java application in order to communicate with an HTML server: I need to POST a form and GET results, in HTML
Using Wireshark, I caught the content of the package I should send. It's something like this:

```
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwU[..]
[...]__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWJAK9%2Fu[...]
TxTNumeroPalina=3329&ListaLocalit%C3%A0=NAPOLI&TxTViaInteresse=&TxTCAP=&BtnInviaDati=Invia+Dati
```

Where dots stand for other random chars.
I should receive back a page containing some timelines for buses. I tried this way.

```
String eventTarget = "__EVENTTARGET" + "=" + "&";
String eventArgument = "__EVENTARGUMENT" + "=" + "&";
String viewState = "__VIEWSTATE" + "=" + "%2FwEPDwUJMj[...]";
String eventValidation = "__EVENTVALIDATION" + "=" + "%2FwEWJ[...]";

String eventObjects = eventTarget + eventArgument + viewState + eventValidation;

//form parameters
String numeroPalina = "TxtNumeroPalina" + "=" + "3329" + "&";
String listaLocalita = "Listalocalit%C3%A0" + "=" + "NAPOLI" + "&";
String viaInteresse = "TxtViaInteresse" + "=" + "" + "&";
String cap = "TxtCAP" + "=" + "";
String sendButton = "BtnInviaDati" + "=" + "Invia+Dati";
String locatorObjects = numeroPalina + listaLocalita + viaInteresse + cap;
String newData = URLEncoder.encode(eventTarget + eventArgument + viewState + eventValidation + locatorObjects, "UTF-8");

URL infoclickUrl = new URL("http://www.anm.it/Default.aspx");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)infoclickUrl.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
streamWriter.write(newData);
streamWriter.flush();
BufferedReader streamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line;
String page="";
while ((line = streamReader.readLine()) != null) {
page += line;
}

streamReader.close();
streamWriter.close();
```

I can never get a correct result from it! What's wrong with it?

---> Edit:
In http://www.anm.it/Default.aspx you can compile a form with a certain bus stop, send it and get in return the timetable of the selected bus stop (arriving buses). So, I should receive an html page with the result of my query in it (if I send the form via browser, it works). With the code I wrote, I get back just an html page containing the initial page.

Comment: define "correct result" and show what you are actually receiving

Comment: If you use HTTP, why not use, for instance, Apache Common's HTTPClient?

Comment: I see the data is received as a multi step process. I however see you are only making a single request. It would help if you show us the entire URL that mentioned as working in the post.

Comment: The URL I'm referring to is http://www.anm.it/Default.aspx, and it works if I use it via browser. I was wondering how can I create and send a form for this URL and get results, all in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling `cookies` in your java code. Try using  firefox's `live http header` addon and see what all data is exchanged between the browser and server. Try sending the below given cookie from your java code.

> Cookie: ISAWPLB{6DC6CE50-2F43-4F96-92BC-840EFF24E706}={23855B49-8C3B-43BA-B5FB-41A85FDD9F3C}

I still believe you should use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) for your aplpication.

Answer (score 0):

Screen Scraping 101

1. POST does not always translate to the full url:

   ```
   URL infoclickUrl = new URL("http://www.anm.it/Default.aspx");
   ```

The port URL would be /Default.aspx HTTP X.X

1. Sometimes, servers use Virtual Host, so you need to append Host: anm.it in your header
2. Use a good tracing tool like firebug before starting to code.
3. HTTPUnit / HTMLUnit are perfect for the job